# Set column width for visual lines in Emacs

Tags: emacs, word-wrap

Is there an equivalent to the `fill-column` variable for the "Wrap" mode (`visual-line-mode`) in Emacs? If not, how could I set a limit on the length of visual lines when the window/frame of the buffer is wider ?

Comment: It wasn't clear to me from reading the manual, but I just tried `M-x longlines-mode`, and so far it seems to do what I was looking for.

Comment: Oddly enough, it seems like the longlines-mode documentation is missing in more recent versions of the GNU Emacs Manual, but earlier versions have it.

Comment: For this I found the package [visual-fill-column](https://melpa.org/#/visual-fill-column) which I am very pleased with. Some answers mention longlines-mode having been removed.

Comment: I use [olivetti](https://github.com/rnkn/olivetti) for this. You can also check out [writeroom](https://github.com/joostkremers/writeroom-mode) and [darkroom](https://github.com/joaotavora/darkroom).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In response to this question I created a minor mode called [window-margin](https://github.com/aculich/window-margin.el) that accomplishes what @Stefan suggested in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14012111/462302).

Turn on `window-margin-mode` with:

```
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'turn-on-window-margin-mode)
```

The way you can still do it without installing window-margin is to use the `longlines-mode` that ships with Emacs, but is being phased out since there are some [problems with longlines-mode](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-pretest-bug/2005-08/msg00233.html), but here's the old way to do it if you want:

Turn on `longlines-mode` with something like:

```
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'longlines-mode)
```

which wraps text at the `fill-column`.

Comment: Thank you so much for this useful replacement to `longlines-mode`! I have a couple of minor feature requests, I will add them as issues on GitHub.

Comment: yes, please do request features! there are some other features that i'd also like to implement, as well as fixing a few inevitable quirks that i've already been annoyed by and want to tweak, so your feedback will be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

`longlines-mode` has been removed.  For `visual-line-mode`, the simplest way is to make the window as narrow as you want it to be.  You can do that with `C-x 3` and then adjusting the size of the window.  Or you can set a wide margin or wide fringes.

Comment: I tried `C-x 2` before, but that's not a solution, at least not without a bit of tweaking. For this to work, the new window should have a blank buffer and should be on the right, but that's not what's happening for me. So I am happier with `longlines-mode` for now.

Comment: @Stefan, you're right that adjusting window size and or margins is the right way to go, but there's no easy and automatic way to do that... until now since I just [wrote a minor mode](https://github.com/aculich/window-margin.el) to do it.

Comment: Just to clarify, Stefan probably meant `C-x 3` instead of `C-x 2`

Comment: What window? I'm in console mode.

Comment: "window" in the Emacs sense (not the GUI sense), so they exist in tty frames just as much as in GUI frames.  I.e. you can use `C-x {` and `C-x }` to resize the window after `C-x 3`, or better use the `windresize` package which should hopefully become standard in Emacs-24.5.