# Line wrapping in visual-line-mode

Tags: emacs

Is there a way to make lines wrap at a specific column in `visual-line-mode`? In a virtual console the lines are too long to read comfortably.

Comment: Are you looking for a frame or window that is much larger than the visual line, and wrap the line prematurely before reaching the edge of the window or frame?  You would have a lot of blank space between the edge of the line and the window / frame edge.  The reason I am asking is because visual-line-mode usually wraps at the edge of the window.  So if you set the size of the window or frame to your liking, then the wrapping will also be to your liking.  Breaking the line with a hard-return is `not` visual-line-mode.  Perhaps you are thinking of column length and truncating.

Comment: Perhaps you are thinking of `fill-column`.

Comment: This seems very similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14009223/set-column-width-for-visual-lines-in-emacs). In particular, [this](https://github.com/aculich/window-margin.el) might be interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Try the package [visual-fill-column](https://melpa.org/#/visual-fill-column). It is mentioned int the EmacsWiki article [Visual Line Mode](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/VisualLineMode).

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding an example on what the package does, how to use it and how it helps the OP.

Comment: You are right. To tell the truth I'm still testing, I've just started using it after being a bit frustrated with window window-margin and it is better in a way. I'll expand it later.